# Get template to deduce the exact type of a functions parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I am having trouble getting templates to deduce the exact type of function parameters.

In this example the call of *callit* will not deduce the parameter types I want. The first call of *callitA* will deduce [int, int, int, int]. The second call of *callitB* will deduce [const int &, int &, const int &, int &]. Only when I make a specific instantiation of the template do I get the correct parameters.

How do I get the behaviour as in 3 below without specifying the template parameters explicitly. They should be deducible from the function parameters.

Thanks in advance.

```
void read() {}

template< typename P, typename... Args >
void read(const P & p, Args&... args) {
   // p is a constant and shall not be written to.
   read(args...);
}

template< typename P, typename... Args >
void read(P & p, Args&... args) {
   cin >> p;
   read(args...);
}

template< typename... Args >
void callitA(Args... args) {
   read( args... );
}

template< typename... Args >
void callitB(Args&... args) {
   read(args...);
}

// b is the only variable that can be returned from funk.
void funk(const int & a, int & b, const int c, int d) {
   callitA(a, b, c, d);  // 1. Args will be [int, int, int, int]
   callitB(a, b, c, d);  // 2. Args will be [const int &, int &, const int &, int &]

   // 3. Here Args will be what I want [const int &, int &, const int, int]
   callitA<const int &, int &, const int, int>(a, b, c, d);
}

void main() {
   const int a = 1;
   int b = 0;
   const int c = 3;
   int d = 4;

   funk(a, b, c, d);

   cout << b << endl;
}
```

Comment: Your approach cannot work with a single pack. Template arguments are always deduced from *values*, not from *variables*. And values are never references. Being a reference or not is sort of an orthogonal property that has nothing to do with values.

Comment: While you're experimenting with references and argument deduction, consider experimenting with `std::ref` also.

Comment: You can use "universal references": `template<class... Args> void callitC(Args&&...);` and `callitC(a, b, std::move(c), std::move(d));` (the moves are required because `c` and `d` are lvalues). The deduced types are: `const int&, int&, const int, int` When having two function templates, you can use this via perfect forwarding to get rid of the explicit moves.

Comment: Perfect forwarding can also be emulated via `#define FWD(x) (std::forward<decltype(x)>(x))` and then `callitC(FWD(a), FWD(b), FWD(c), FWD(d));`

Answer (score 0):

Inside your function `func()` all four parameters are lvalues and it is indistinguishable that `c` and `d` are parameters. If you mean `c` and `d` to be rvalues when looked at by `callitA()`, you'd need to `std::move()` them.

Below is a program which does a better job at deducing the passed arguments:

```
#include <iostream>

void read() {
    std::cout << '\n';
}

template <typename T>
struct type_to_string;
template <>
struct type_to_string<int&> {
    static constexpr char const* value = "int&";
};
template <>
struct type_to_string<int const&> {
    static constexpr char const* value = "int const&";
};
template <>
struct type_to_string<int> {
    static constexpr char const* value = "int";
};

template <>
struct type_to_string<int const> {
    static constexpr char const* value = "int const";
};

template< typename P, typename... Args >
void read(P&&, Args&&... args) {
    std::cout << type_to_string<P>::value << ", ";
    read(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

template< typename... Args >
void callitA(Args... args) {
   read( args... );
}

template< typename... Args >
void callitB(Args&... args) {
   read(args...);
}

template< typename... Args >
void callitC(Args&&... args) {
    read(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}

void funk(const int & a, int & b, const int c, int d) {
   callitA(a, b, c, d);
   callitB(a, b, c, d);
   callitC(a, b, std::move(c), std::move(d));
}

int main() {
   const int a = 1;
   int b = 0;
   const int c = 3;
   int d = 4;

   funk(a, b, c, d);
   callitC(a, b, static_cast<int const>(3), 4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers. There are a lot of interesting things in there.
Unfortunately this is the only way I seem to be able to do what I want.

The program below produces the following output:
int const, int, int const, int const,
int const, int, int const, int const,

The important thing is that only the second parameter 'b' is non-const so I can overload a read function to only read this parameter.

```
void read() {
   std::cout << '\n';
}

template <typename T>
struct type_to_string;
template <>
struct type_to_string<int&> {
   static char const* value;
};
char const* type_to_string<int&>::value = "int&";
template <>
struct type_to_string<int const&> {
   static char const* value;
};
char const* type_to_string<int const&>::value = "int const&";
template <>
struct type_to_string<int> {
   static char const* value;
};
char const* type_to_string<int>::value = "int";

template <>
struct type_to_string<int const> {
   static char const* value;
};
char const* type_to_string<int const>::value = "int const";

template< typename P, typename... Args >
void read(P&, Args&... args) {
   cout << type_to_string<P>::value << ", ";
   read( args...);
}

template< typename... Args >
void callitC(Args&... args) {
   read( args...);
}

// b is the only variable that can be returned from funk.
void funkA(const int & a, int & b, const int c, int d) {
   callitC(a, b, c, const_cast<const int &>(d));
}

// b is the only variable that can be returned from funk.
void funkB(const int & a, int & b, const int c, int d) {
   callitC<const int &, int &, const int, const int>(a, b, c, d);
}

void main() {
   const int a = 1;
   int b = 0;
   const int c = 3;
   int d = 4;

   funk(a, b, c, d);
   cout << endl;
   funkB(a, b, c, d);
}
```